# Matlab Cumulative sum

Tags: matlab, cumsum

I'm working in matlab with `cumsum` function. Now I want to know when cumsum of an array reaches it's closest position to a number. For example;

When will `cumsum(week1(1,13:17))` reaches it's closest position to 800.

```
week 1 13:17 = 200 200 200 400 900
cumsum(week1(1,13:17))= 400 600 1000 1900
```

So how can I find that it's closest position is 15?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

ok it is clear from this  ,that at 13  it was  400,at 14 it was  600,at 15 it was 1000,now  you can check  in matlab program    using if that if  cumsum(array)>800,break;also please  save indexes  and you cna easily find then it:
EDITED :

```
>> A=[200 200 200 400 900];
>> sum=cumsum(A);
>> i=1;
while sum(i)<=800
  i=i+1;
   if sum(i)>800
   i=i-1;
end
end

>> i

i =

     3
```

now you have

```
13:17

ans =

    13    14    15    16    17
```

you can determine easily

Answer (score 0):

Finding the location with minimum distance to a certain value can be as simple as this:

```
w = [200 200 200 400 900];
cw = cumsum(w);

[v, loc] = min(abs(cw-600))
```

Note that you would be interested in `loc+12` in this case as in this example `w` only contains elements 13 and further.